# Linux Raspbian (raspberry Pi) crontab not running sh. Works fine running manually

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, cron, raspbian

I've tried every which way to get this working. I originally created a Python script to interact with Twitter. The script runs fine and does what it should do. I added to crontab, but it wouldn't run. I then heard there was some trouble with interaction directly with Python, so wrote a launcher.sh to run the Python script and added this to crontab. Still a no go. The Launcher.sh is executable and running manually works fine. Here's the code:

`sudo sh launcher.sh` runs fine - this contains a script to run a python script
content of launcher:

```
#!/bin/sh
# launcher.sh
# navigate to home directory

cd /
cd home/pi
sudo python retweet.py
cd /
```

In root crontab I have (note this is the root crontab `sudo crontab -e`):

```
@reboot 0,15,30,45 * * * * sh /home/pi/launcher.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This is to run it every 15 minutes. I've also tried `/15 * * * *`

I've checked the syslog and can see that after a reboot as per this line, that crontab ackknowledges the start on reboot request.

The script however never runs.
Here's the syslog:

```
Jan 22 09:36:12 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2113]: (root) CMD (0,15,30,45 * * * *           sh /home/pi/laucher.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 )
```

I'm pretty new to the world of Linux, I've read lots and am learning as I go. I hope someone out there can help me.

Comment: If root will run the script there's no need for `sudo`. (Also `cd /; cd home/pi` could be just `cd /home/pi` (if there's an actual need for a certain working directory at all), and there's no need to `cd` anywhere at the end of the script.) BTW, how do you know the script doesn't run?

Comment: Thanks for that Skynet - I have tried many different incarnations and followed guidance around the web. I can confirm the change hasn't worked :(. What am I missing here? executing either the Python script directly, or the launcher.sh both perform the task fine. I previously (before I made the launcher) had in crontab the link directly to the python script, so @reboot 0,15,30,45 * * * * python /home/pi/retweet.py and that didn't work either

Comment: *How* do you know the script isn't executed? For debugging purposes you could pipe the output to a file (instead of `/dev/null`), and/or add some logging in the Python script. And add `set -x` at the top of the shell script.

Comment: So the script in Python looks for certain hashtags and gives them a retweet. I'm looking at the most recent hashtags and can see they're more recent (by hours) than the last the account retweeted. On running it manually (I don't want to push a massive amount through the twitter API at once so am having to run manually every hour or so) will get on average 12 retweets processed going back over the hour. I know they're there, I can see them in the feed. They're not being processed by the script.

Comment: The Python script may very well be *running* from cron, but something *inside* the script could fail. Without seeing the script we can only guess, and my guess is on authentication problems. Unless you try to get some more feedback from cron, sh and Python there's not much one can do to help.

Comment: Sad times - in terms of authentication, I take it you don't mean via the Twitter API? As mentioned, the script works fine everytime when run manually. It's only when I try to automate via crontab I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: There are all kinds of things that the script could be doing that could fail when run from cron. For instance if it relies on environment variables that aren't set. Have you tested the script when "su"ed to root? (as opposed to sudo). Additionally, I would highly recommend piping the output to a  log file as suggested above.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Joe. I'm away from the Pi at the moment, but will update with the full info later. Thanks all.

Comment: This is the code it's based on. The only things that have been modifed are the search term and auth/tokens/secrets for twitter: https://github.com/basti2342/retweet-bot

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your comments - it was a rookie error on my part. Simply put, you can't have @reboot followed by the time specification. 0 * * * * *. I've removed the @reboot command, and it's all working fine now.